# Autocopy cell value from one cell to another sheet by clicking an icon in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I would like to copy cell value from cell A2 to a new spreadsheet by clicking on an icon in C2.

Preferable I would like to add a timestamp to my new spreadsheet when someone clicks on C2.

Could someone help me out with this matter?

I have made a test spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SUqqwr2fGZTDFMyCw9WRWUljSoHUO05X_a0arqLPUdo/edit#gid=0

The icon should be clickable by an anonymous user not only by the editor of the sheet.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi ! I see that you have achieved this in a certain way in your script (when I click D1 in Ark 2 cell A1 is copy/pasted along with the Timestamp. Was that what you were aiming to achieve? Or do you want save the data with the timestamp of every click done? (right now the data is been overwritten in A1 with every click)

Comment: Yes Matoe. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The data been overwritten is perfectly fine with me. thanks for your comment. As you can I had help from someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in another forum and here I got this answer which helped me out this time.
Thanks to Kishan for helping me out. 
The answer is posted here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/31690663?hl=en