# Using one script for copying text from cells in a row to another sheet using an icon in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

From my previous post ([Autocopy cell value from one cell to another sheet by clicking an icon in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449979/autocopy-cell-value-from-one-cell-to-another-sheet-by-clicking-an-icon-in-google)) I now run into a new problem which I would like someone to help me out with.

I'm trying to achieve a spreadsheet where an anonymous user can click the icon in column A and the data from column B and C is moved from sheet1 to sheet2 including a timestamp.

So far so good. It is up and running with a help from this great community. I'm using this script:

```
function copyPasteValue2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Ark1');
  var r = s.getRange('b2');
  var v = r.getValue();
  var a = s.getRange('c2');
  var d = a.getValue();
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Ark2');
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy');
  s2.getRange('A2:C2').setValues([[t,v,d]]);
}
```

Now I'm looking at scaling this sheet up and contain more than 100 entries all with this ability - click on an icon in column A and move data in C and B to sheet 2.

My question is, how can I achieve this without creating another 100 scripts? As I'm slowly progressing here my search hasn't returned in a solution so far.

I have made a test sheet for any help here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5TGWp3N002z0GNts4NRyspkjXcsN52rxPtx8Pu9D70/edit#gid=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to run the script by clicking the image on Spreadsheet.
- You want to put the images for the column "A". In this case, you want to put a lot of images.
- You want to achieve this using the simple script.

### Issue and workaround:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the script is run by clicking the image on the sheet, the script cannot know where the image is clicked. By this, unfortunately, in your case, when you want to run the script by clicking the image, it is required to assign each image with the different function name.
- And also, when the script is run by clicking the image, it seems that the function is searched before the global variables are run. By this, automatically installing functions using the script cannot be achieved.

From above situation, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the images assigned the functions are used. In this case, as the sample, it supposes that 5 images are put to the sheet of `Ark1`, and each images has the function names like `copyPasteValue2`, `copyPasteValue3` and so on.

#### Sample script:

The sample script is as follows. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

```
function main(row) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Ark1');
  var [v, d] = s.getRange(`B${row}:C${row}`).getValues()[0];
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Ark2');
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy');
  s2.getRange(`A${row}:C${row}`).setValues([[t,v,d]]);
}

const copyPasteValue2 = () => main(2);
const copyPasteValue3 = () => main(3);
const copyPasteValue4 = () => main(4);
const copyPasteValue5 = () => main(5);
const copyPasteValue6 = () => main(6);
```

- In this script, when the image which has the function name of `copyPasteValue2` is clicked, `2` which is the row of the image is given to the function of `main()`. By this, `copyPasteValue2` can be run as the row 2.

#### Note:

- About `const copyPasteValue2 = () => main(2); const copyPasteValue3 = () => main(3); ,,,`, the format is constant. So for example, I think that you can also create these script as a text file, then you can copy and paste them to the script editor.
- If you want to insert the images to the column "A" using a script, you can use the following function. When you use this, please set the file ID of the image on Google Drive. And please set `sheetName` and `max`.

  ```
  function insertImages() {
    var id = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the image.
    var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
    var max = 5;  // Please set the number of images you want to put.

    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.setRowHeights(2, max, 64).setColumnWidth(1, 64);
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, i + 2).setHeight(64).setWidth(64).assignScript("copyPasteValue" + (i + 2));
    }
  }
  ```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, I would like to propose to use the checkboxes instead of the image. In this case, using the OnEdit event trigger, when the checkbox is clicked, it can know the coordinate of the checkbox which was clicked. By this, the script can become simpler than that of pattern 1.

#### Sample script:

```
function main(row) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Ark1');
  var [v, d] = s.getRange(`B${row}:C${row}`).getValues()[0];
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Ark2');
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy');
  s2.getRange(`A${row}:C${row}`).setValues([[t,v,d]]);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Ark1" && e.value == "TRUE") {
    main(range.rowStart);
    range.uncheck();
  }
}
```

- At above script, it supposes that the column "A" on the sheet of `Ark1` has the checkboxes.
- In this case, you can run the script using the simple trigger.

### Note:

- In this case, please enable V8 at the script editor.

### References:

- [Class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your deep answer @Tanaike. I'm using your suggestion with patttern 2. Much more easy to use and setup for a newbie like me. It really made my day. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jesper Homann Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.