# Assigning a macro to a cell instead of a drawing/text box

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros, google-apps-script-api

Is it possible to assign a macro/script to a cell in Google Sheets to cut out the need to have a drawing/text box to assign it to? I have a header in `A1` which, when clicked, I would like to to take me to another sheet. The script I have works, it just looks a bit messy with a button over the cell

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your issue, for example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60505997/7108653

Comment: Not from my understanding of the detail in the link you kindly provided @Tanaike. Basically I have a 'Home' sheet and from here I wish to be able to click cell ```A1``` and for it to automatically take me to a sheet titled '01'. I have a working macro for this but presently I have to use the drawing feature to create a box to place over cell ```A1``` to be able to assign the macro. Ideally I would want to bypass the need for a text box/drawing and simply assign the macro so when I click on ```A1``` the macro runs. Hope this makes more sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your situation from your replying. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Not a problem @Tanaike, I appreciate your responses. Here is a reduced version of my spreadsheet......https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u6ESDwyp1tsy_NCP9BBhmy0POKBBnh9iP-zCV2l1V3c/edit?usp=sharing...…..from this I wish for the cell containing "Class 01" in cell ```A1``` of the sheet titled 'Home' to take me to the sheet titled '01' when I click on it

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I could open it. But I cannot find your current script. Where can I see it?