# Published google sheet with scripts not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From my previous post at [Using one script for copying text from cells in a row to another sheet using an icon in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505997/using-one-script-for-copying-text-from-cells-in-a-row-to-another-sheet-using-an) I have made a great solution for moving a row by marking a checkbox thanks to @Tanaike.

I need this spreadsheet to be published online and anonymous users to mark the checkbox in column A. 
When they click the checkbox the text is moved to sheet 2.

The thing is. The script works fine for an anonymous user with a link but not when it is published online.

I have made a test sheet for you to look into. What am I doing wrong?

Sheet with a link for anonymous user that works fine: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5TGWp3N002z0GNts4NRyspkjXcsN52rxPtx8Pu9D70/edit#gid=0

Sheet with a a published link for anonymous user that doesn't work https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT7xrS6irhVTHQzsvM-RdBU6rTDyWFGtHlfTMTAGzG3OqxTnL4uoEKfNo5jxrbvHppAox2VXOnev4yP/pubhtml#

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish a file via `File > Publish to the web`, you make the file contents visible to anyone, but these contents are not the same as the file itself. These published contents cannot be directly updated (the content will be updated if you edit the spreadsheet where the data comes from) and, of course, you cannot fire an Apps Script trigger from there either.

If you want anonymous users to be able to fire the script when they click the checkbox, you should share the file itself via `Share > Advanced > Public on the web`, and change the access role to `Can edit`.

#### Reference:

- [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @lamblichus. I thought so but hoped I could make it work in a published version.

Comment: My problem is the users have to see it on an iPad while driving so everything I can remove from the screen is the best solution. I thought it would be a published version since I also need to be able to fire a link with one click action.