# Moving rows from multiple sheets with checkbox and script to one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With help from this great community I have made a script where I can move a row to another sheet by clicking a checkbox in column A.
[Using one script for copying text from cells in a row to another sheet using an icon in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505997/using-one-script-for-copying-text-from-cells-in-a-row-to-another-sheet-using-an)

I need more sheets with this checkbox functionality. Ie Ark2, Ark3 and so on.
All should move data in row to sheet "Sick" without overwriting existing data.

From my existing script only one sheet "Ark1" is functioning and I'm sure it will overwrite in sheet "Sick" if I just copy the script and replace names on the sheets.

Here is the script I'm using.

```
function main(row) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Ark1');
  var [v, d] = s.getRange(`B${row}:C${row}`).getValues()[0];
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sick');
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy');
  s2.getRange(`A${row}:C${row}`).setValues([[t,v,d]]);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Ark1" && e.value == "TRUE") {
    main(range.rowStart);
    range.uncheck();
  }
}
```

An editable test version of my sheet can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5TGWp3N002z0GNts4NRyspkjXcsN52rxPtx8Pu9D70/edit#gid=1278602995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to get the name of the edited Sheet rather than specifying "Ark1", and add it to the bottom of the sheet "Sick" using the `getLastRow()` method.*

#### Code Changes:

```js
function main(range) {
  var row = range.rowStart;
  var s = range.getSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var [v, d] = s.getRange(`B${row}:C${row}`).getValues()[0];
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sick');
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy');
  s2.getRange(`A${s2.getLastRow() + 1}:C${s2.getLastRow() + 1}`).setValues([[t,v,d]]);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != "Sick" && e.value == "TRUE") {
    main(range);
    range.uncheck();
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Method `getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

Comment: This is great and works pretty good -  almost.
The script will move the same row twice to sheet "sick". So I get 2 identical entries. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: On each click it will only move a row once, but clicking again will make it copy a second time. Is this not how you want it?

Comment: This is exactly how I want it. One click will move the row. Next time I click again. The row is moved again. 
But with this script the row is moved twice.

Comment: I think this is to with how you had multiple projects/triggers before hand. This only occurs on your sheet for Ark1, not Ark2, and also on my test sheet I do not get the duplication - create a new Spreadsheet, set up a test sheet or two and copy+paste the code in and it should work with no issue. I'm still looking into the root cause of why it's doing this though.

Comment: If you have an installable trigger on the project which executes `main()` this might be the cause, do you have anything like this?

Comment: Have you been able to sort out the duplication issue?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Family needed assistance...
Yes I managed to copy it to a new spreadsheet. And now it works perfectly. It must have something to do with multiple triggers as I have been fooling around with that document for a while. Thanks for your help @rafa guillermo