# How can i create a button in a cell using only google app script? not with the Insert>drawing option

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to do a button with a script its required for the thing i want to do so the button that can be created in `insert>draw` option doesn't have what i need, i want to put a entire call with buttons in each row son any button execute a function when is clicked, I want to know if this is possible

***I looked about this information here, but really dont know how to do it***

[Using one script for copying text from cells in a row to another sheet using an icon in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505997/using-one-script-for-copying-text-from-cells-in-a-row-to-another-sheet-using-an)

***Script in my html that embed my trello cards***

```js
  <script>

  (() => {

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myname => {

      const tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://p.trellocdn.com/embed.min.js";

      tag.addEventListener('load', () => {

        const elem = document.querySelector('#card');

        elem.href = myname;

        window.TrelloCards.load(document); // <-- this triggers the lookup
      });

      document.body.append(tag);

    }).getCardById();

  })();
  </script>
```

***Function `getCardById`***

```js
function getCardById(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSp = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSp.getActiveSheet();
  //Range of links
  var linkRange = activeSheet.getRange(2,2,3,1);
  //Cuantity of values
  var filLength = linkRange.getValues();
  var cont = 2;
  if (activeSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6.0){
    for (i = 0; i < filLength.length ; i++){
      if (activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow() == activeSheet.getRange(cont,2).getRow()){ 
        var linkCol = 2.0;
        var linkFil = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
        var linkRange = activeSheet.getRange(linkFil, linkCol);
        var linkValue = linkRange.getValue();
        var url = linkValue;
        return url;
      }
      cont++;
    }
  }
}
```

***Function `seeCard` its the one that should be displayed when pressing the checkbox, when you press it should show you values of the same row***

```js
function seeCard(){
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSp = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSp.getActiveSheet();
  var startCol = 6;
  var startFil = 2;
  var numCols = 1;
  var numFils = 2;

  //Rango de links
  var linkRange = activeSheet.getRange(2,2,3,1);
  //Cantidad de valores para el for 
  var filLength = linkRange.getValues();
  var cont = 2;

  if (activeSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6.0){
    for (i = 0; i < filLength.length ; i++){
      if (activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow() == activeSheet.getRange(cont,2).getRow()){ 
        //Html
        var templateFileId = '1upA3JHioEyxLScebasmsmwXW-SxsiKaPRznKLCKFYhw';
        var sheetName = 'Trello sheet';
        SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateFileId).copy(sheetName);
        var excel =  SpreadsheetApp.create("Probando un html interno a ver ")
        var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') //index is the name of your HTML file
        .setTitle('Trello card')
        .setWidth(350)
        .setHeight(250);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'trello card '); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        //End
      }
      cont++;
    }
  }
}
```

***Where is the button that says `seeCard` i need to put the checkbox and when you click grab the link send it to my html and show the trello card attached to that link***

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the button you expect. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The button your referring to is part of card-service and is used in add-ons.  I don't think it's possible to create a button in a spreadsheet cell with script.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes you can ask for details

Comment: @Cooper you don't know how can i put a method to a cell them?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you explain about the detail of the goal using the button you expect? For example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60505997/7108653

Comment: You can run functions with checkboxes and an onedit trigger.  I understand that's how some users are adding functionality to mobile versions of sheets.

Comment: @Cooper that sounds good can you please give an example?

Comment: @Tanaike yes you are right, now i will like you to help to implement the `patter 2` in my own code i will post it in this same question

Comment: Thank you for replying. At [the pattern 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60505997/7108653), the checkbox is used instead of the image button. But I cannot understand about the detail of your goal. So I have asked about the detail of the goal using the button you expect.

Comment: @Tanaike Something like the `patter 2` should work for me too, but i need help to do it correctly, see my updated question

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your updated question, I couldn't understand about `Function seeCard its the one that should be displayed when pressing the checkbox, when you press it should show you values of the same row`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes you can ask, right now my function `seeCard` is attached to a button that was draw with the options of google sheets, the problem is that i need to know the row and the column of the button so when you press it you can display an html and the html will display a script that needs to know the column an row of the button too so they can work

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, at first, please decide the column you want to put the checkbox. By this, when a checkbox is clicked, the row of the checkbox can be retrieved by the event object of OnEdit event trigger, and you can run the function of `seeCard()` using the values of the row.

Comment: Yes thanks @Tanaike see the picture i post

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to put the checkboxes to the cells of "F2:F".
- You want to run `seeCard()` when the checkbox is checked.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script. And, [please install OnEdit event trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Because in your script, when a simple trigger is used, an error occurs at the methods which are required to authorize like `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` and `SpreadsheetApp.create()`. So please use the installable OnEdit event trigger for this.

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.columnStart == 6 && range.rowStart > 1 && range.isChecked()) {
    range.uncheck();
    seeCard();
  }
}
```

- In order to run the script, please check a checkbox at the column "F". By this, the function of `installedOnEdit` is run by the installable OnEdit event trigger. In your script, the active range is retrieved from your script. So in your case, I think that this sample script works.

#### Note:

- I thought that the event object can be also used. But I'm not sure about your whole script. So I couldn't propose it.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet13') {
    if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==1 ) {
      e.range.setValue('FALSE');
      one(e);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==1 ) {
      e.range.setValue('FALSE')
      two(e);
    }
  }
}

function one(e) {
  e.source.toast('This is function one');
}


function two(e) {
  e.source.toast('This is function two');
}
```

Image:

[image]

Animation:

[image]